# Sending SQL query with reading from text file

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, vbscript

http://myitforum.com/cs2/blogs/dhite/archive/2008/05/26/vbs-script-to-send-sql-queries-for-installed-collections-to-excel.aspx
Not answering because this is about VBS to Excel.

[Valid SQL query fails when executed from VB Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15482566/valid-sql-query-fails-when-executed-from-vb-script)
I am too stupid to understand script that is written by user, answer neither.

Continuing to type all I found is just lost of time, reasons are almost equally same.

Clue is, I am searching for VBS script, that could load string from file for example (file: xyz.txt), connect to database, after suitable data is provided... and send it... like `INSERT INTO xyz VALUES (ABC, DEF)`. Is there anyway to do it without opening extra windows?

Answer (score 2):

Given a file XYZ.TXT containing the data I want to have in a MySQL table, I would try to

- use [load data infile](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) to let the DBMS do the heavy lifting

or

- use an ADODB.Command with a statement like "INSERT INTO T VALUES (?, ... ?)" and [.Execute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681559%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) it passing an array build with Split() from .ReadLine()s on the .txt file

Comment: Thanks for answering. So, I just looked up on two things you gave to me. The first one, seem to be too heavy for server, it has to be as light as possible. The second one, is not clear to me, could you explain the second one please?

Comment: @RikTelner If you want to insert data into a database table, you basically have 2 options: doing a bulk load, or doing a series of inserts. Of those 2 the former usually puts less load on the server.